# How to follow (a la "tail -f") a binary file from the beginning?

Tags: text-processing, tail, binary

Is it possible to follow a binary file from the beginning, a la `tail -f`?

This is useful in some cases, for example if I'm `scp`ing a file to a remote server, and at the same time I want to feed it to another process (yes, I know I can use `ssh`+`cat` tricks).

As far as I read from the FM, `tail` is written having text files in mind.

Is there any simple way of doing such operations using standard posix tools?

Comment: Where does it say that `tail` can only be used with text files?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz On older unices, text-oriented utilities such as `tail` didn't always cope with binary files: they might choke on null bytes or omit stray bytes after the last newline in the input files. Modern systems do cope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`tail` works with binary data just as well as with text. If you want to start at the very beginning of the file, you can use `tail -c +1 -f`.

Comment: Is this not working for anyone? I have a binary file that has 16 occurrences of a string that I see when I use `cat bin_file | strings - -o | grep match_string`, but when I do `tail -c +1 -f bin_file | strings - -o | grep match_string`, I get nothing past the 9th match. I also noted that the line numbers from `-o` are all 1 less compared to the cat output. If I leave the grep off, I get all 16 matches (mixed in with everything else), so I thought the problem was grep, but I tried a perl one-liner and it stops in the same place...